# Как распараллелить цикл?

Tags: openmp

У меня есть примерно след. код

```
for (;;)
{
   do
  {
   //тут нужно расспараллелить
  }
}
```

Хотел бы распараллелить то что в цикле. Но беда в том, что если я напишу #pragma omp parallel там где нужно распараллелить, оно будет создавать и удалять потоки столько раз, сколько выполнится do. А я бы хотел как то внешне сказать, что надо создать два потока, которые будут выполнять вот этот код, при этом их не надо удалять и создавать по 100500 раз.

Answer (score 1):

omp_set_dynamic + omp_set_num_threads позволят запретить менять число потоков и установить это самое число, соответственно.

Answer (score 0):

Потоки будут созданы при входе в #pragma omp parallel. Далее им будут поручаться итерации, потоки будут продолжать жить, не уничтожаясь. Так возможно будет распараллелить только for.